# Create table rows from textarea items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to take input from a textarea and generate table rows in an existing table body.

**Input:** (items separated by each new line in the textarea input)

```
<textarea name="excel_data"></textarea>
<input id="test" type="button" value="Enter Items"/>
```

**textarea lines insert into `<tbody>`**

```
<tbody class="output">
    <!-- Append Rows Here -->
</tbody>
```

Using the below I get an entire new table into `<tbody>`.  How do I get just the `<tr>` row from `var markup`?  Editing `var table` and `var row` for tr or td elements either gives errors or nothing at all.  What am I missing?

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
    console.log(data);
    var rows = data.split("\n");

    var table = $('<tr />');

    for(var y in rows) {
        var cells = rows[y].split("\t");

        for(var x in cells) {

        var markup = 
            +'<td><span class="fsize14">'+cells[x]+'</span><input type="hidden" id="part" value="'+cells[x]+'" name="part[]"><br><input type="text" id="datasheet" class="" name="datasheet[]" placeholder="Data sheet (URL)..."></td>'
            +'<td> sadgsdg  <input type="hidden" id="descrip" value="" name="descrip[]"></td>'
            +'<td><input required type="text" id="qty" class="form-control qty" value="" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty"></td>'
            +'<td>'
                +'<div class="input-group">'
                +'<div class="input-group-addon">&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>&nbsp;</div>'
                    +'<input required type="text" id="price" class="form-control price" value="" name="price[]" placeholder="Price">'
                +'</div>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td>'
                +'<div class="input-group">'
                +'<div class="input-group-addon">&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>&nbsp;</div>'
                    +'<input type="text" id="net" class="form-control total" value="0.00" name="net[]" placeholder="Total">'
                +'</div>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td><input type="text" id="notes" class="form-control" name="notes[]" placeholder="Notes..."></td>'
            +'<td><div class="deleteRow"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle text-danger"></i></div></td>'
            ;
        }

    table.append(markup);
    }
    $('.output').html(table);
});
```

Comment: You're inserting `<tr>` into `<tr>`.

Comment: I implore you to use a framework for this.